# FOMUnsupportedTextTypeException: Unsupported Text Type: text/html

Tags: websphere-portal, apache-abdera

I am trying to parse the response atom feed received from websphere portal after rest call using apache abdera. However receiving the below error when parsing. Could some one let me know what the issue is?

org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMUnsupportedTextTypeException: Unsupported Text Type: text/html

```
    Abdera abdera = new Abdera();
    AbderaClient abderaClient = new AbderaClient(abdera);
    Factory factory = abdera.getFactory();        
    Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie ltpaCookieHttpCommons = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie();
    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions(true);
    List<String> cookieStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    options.setHeader("Cookie", (String[])cookieStrings.toArray(new String[cookieStrings.size()]));

    ClientResponse resp = abderaClient.get("http://localhost:10039/wps/contenthandler/!ut/p/digest!W9TQFjuU7ADCwtSkxDsxHg/searchfeed/search?queryLang=en&locale=en&resultLang=en&query=test&scope=com.ibm.lotus.search.ALL_SOURCES&start=0&results=10&output=application/xml", options);
    System.out.println(resp.getType());
    if (resp.getType() == ResponseType.SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!Response success!!!!!!");
        Document<Feed> docFeed = resp.getDocument();
        // JSON Output
        Writer writer = abdera.getWriterFactory().getWriter("json");
        try { 
            Feed feed=docFeed.getRoot();

            abdera.getWriterFactory().getWriter("json").writeTo(feed, System.out);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the atom feed your parsing has a type tag with `text/html` in it which isn't in the [atom spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-3.1.1) so abdera throws the above error.

According to the spec:

> When present, the value
> MUST be one of "text", "html", or "xhtml"

Are you sure the feed is an atom feed and not an RSS feed which supports enclosures with MIME types like the one above ?

Comment: its valid, coming from webphere. I think it had some ibm specific namespaces. I parsed it manually using javascript.

Comment: It may be coming from websphere so there's nothing you can do about it but it's not valid atom was my point, so abdera couldn't be used until it was modified first.